# Controller not executing code (Blazor server-side)

Tags: authentication, cookies, controller, blazor, blazor-editform

**My Goal** Create a simple login form in order to authenticate and authorize the user in my Blazor Server-side app with Cookie Authentication.

**My Issue** Everything works... The EditForm passes the values to my Controller. The Controller validates the usercredentials. Then runs HttpContext.SignInAsync(claims) and returns Ok().
But the Cookie is not passed and the user is not Authenticate either.

**What I have done**

**1. The EditForm, passes the userinputs to the DisplayLoginModel() on a ValidSubmit.**

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
        <EditForm Model="@userLogin" OnValidSubmit="OnValidLogin">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <ValidationSummary />
            <div class="mb-4 row">
                <p class="col-sm-4 font-weight-bold">Email</p>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <InputText @bind-Value="userLogin.Email" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4 row">
                <p class="col-sm-4 font-weight-bold">Password</p>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <InputText @bind-Value="userLogin.Password" class="form-control"  />
                </div>
            </div>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary col-sm-4" type="submit"><strong>Login EditForm</strong></button>
        </EditForm>
    </div>
</div>
```

**2. The OnValidLogin Sends a request to the Form Controller**

```
        public DisplayLoginModel userLogin = new DisplayLoginModel();
    private async Task OnValidLogin()
    {
        var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            Method = new HttpMethod("POST"),
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://localhost:44370/Form"),
            Content = JsonContent.Create(userLogin)      
        };
        var client = httpfac.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);           
    }
```

**3. The Controller gets the user credentials from the displayloginModel and validets Ok().**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post(DisplayLoginModel _userLogin)
    {       
        if (_userLogin.Email == "this@Email.com")
        {     
            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "ActiveUser")
            }, "auth");
            ClaimsPrincipal claims = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claims);         
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

**4. Startup.cs**

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddHttpClient();
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); 
        services.AddAuthentication("Cookies").AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.SlidingExpiration = true; 
        });        
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    }
```

And

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication(); 
        app.UseAuthorization(); 
        
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
```

Why is the Controller not signing the user in, what am I missing?

An image of the solution structure is seen right below:

[image]

Comment: Could you please post in your question an image of the solution structure...

Answer (score 0):

Because Blazor Server uses websockets (Blazor circuits) to render the UI while on the controller, `await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claims);` returns a `cookie` header so the browser can be authorized on next page load. This means you are actually being authenticated server-side but not from the client-side as you have not reloaded the page context to update the cookies. There is a reason why the default Identity login uses MVC architecture for the authentication process. :)

My suggestion, switch to API-based authentication/authorization or use a traditional login in flow.